# Kafka Consumer : controlled reading from topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, bigdata

I have below kafka consumer code where 3 threads are reading from kafka Topic having 3 partitions.

Is there any way, where new message will be read from the kafka topic only after the messages currently being in process by the thread got processed.

For example lets say there are 100 messages in topic, so is there any way where only 3 messages should be read at a time and processed. Now when these 3 messages gets processed then only next 3 messages should be read and so on.

```
public void run(int a_numThreads) {
Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(a_numThreads));
Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

// now launch all the threads
//
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

// now create an object to consume the messages
//
int threadNumber = 0;
for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
    executor.submit(new ConsumerTest(stream, threadNumber));
    threadNumber++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If iterator inside ConsumerTest is processing message in synchronously then only 3 messages will be consumed at a time. enable.auto.commit is true by default. Make sure you do not set it to false, else you need to add logic for committing offset.

ex-

```
 ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> streamIterator= stream.iterator(); 
 while (streamIterator.hasNext()) { 
   String kafkaMsg= new String(streamIterator.next().message()); 
 }
```

Comment: I had set   properties.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");  like this.if this is correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. One point to notice is this will commit offset every 1 second. If your service crashes then all messages processed in this 1 second interval will not be commited and will be reprocessed when your consumer spins up again (kind of edge cases to consider while designing services). So you need to make sure your consumer logic is fault tolerant to service crash and duplicate message processing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the consumers do not know about each other by default, so the can not "sync" their work. What you could to is either wrap your three messages into one (and thus guaranteeing they all will be answered in order) or maybe introduce more ("sub") topics.

Another possibility (if you really need to guarantee that your three messages will be consumed by individual consumers) might be that all your consumers sync their work or maybe notifying a controller which tracks your work.

But tbh it feels like you "are doing it wrong", actually the messages in a queue are meant to be stateless and only their order in a topic determines their "order in which they should be processed". WHEN the messages are being processed should not matter.

Comment: Hi Nikolas, I am not concerned with ordering of messages. what i want is only N number of messages should be read from topic at point and then when all the processing of these N messages gets over then only next N messages should be fetched.

Comment: Ah, maybe in that case *seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)* might do the trick? But you must be aware that you might lose data if you ask for the offset "at the wrong time". But you could fetch all the data, only read your N messages and discard the rest. Then simply trigger your queue again with the new offset + N?

Comment: This one is really nice approach. till now its working good with me

Comment: Also, consumer must store the last consumed offset for each partition locally. Else ,it might lose the marker to last consumed offset.